# Summing values in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
  coll1[   **coll1 is the collection name**
    {"_id" : ObjectId("571489d66e58990374e0d2d3"), 
         "cbill_details":[ **cbill_details is a json array.**
           {"total-sell":22, "price":1212}, **total-sell represent no of item sold in a perticular bill**
           {"total-sell":24, "price":1512}
          ], **here the total-sell is (22+24)=46.that is whay i want to select this document**
        "product_name":"jeans"
        }, **end of document 1** 
        {"_id" : ObjectId("571489d66e58990374e0d2d4"), 
         "cbill_details":[
           {"total-sell":10, "price":182},
           {"total-sell":15, "price":223}
          ],**here the total-sell is (10+15)=25,which is less than 30 that is whay i donot want to select this document**
        "product_name":"t-shirt"
        } **end of document 2** 
    ]
```

I want to get the documents there the total of the `total-sell` is greater than 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No group needed, just a project and match.

```
db.coll1.aggregate([{
    $project : {
        total: {$sum: "$cbill_details.total-sell"}
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        total: { $gt: 30 }
    }
}])
```

Produces:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("571489d66e58990374e0d2d3"),
    "total" : 46
}
```

Comment: Then use `$redact`. The more pipeline stages the more time taken. It also really needs a note that this is only possible in MongoDB 3.2, and consider that "most" people with production systems are still not using that latest version.

Comment: @BlakesSeven which bit isn't supported pre-3.2?

Comment: `$sum` working on array, or even outside `$group`. It's a big highlighted section in the documentation.

Comment: @BlakesSeven So it is.  Good spot.

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB 3.2 you can use a [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) expression since [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) can actually work directly on an array in that release:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "if": { "$gt": [ { "$sum": "cbill_details.total-sell"  }, 30 ] },
        "then": "$$KEEP",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }}
])
```

In earlier versions, the aggregation expression is not worth the cost, since you need [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in ordere to [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) array elements. So you can alternately do this with [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

```js
db.collection.find(function() {
    return Array.sum(this.cbill_details.map(function(el) {
        return el["total-sell"]
    })) > 30;
})
```

But both of course need to "scan" the entire collection in order to determine which documents to return. So that is not very efficient

The real lesson to learn here should be to keep the total as a property in the document instead. You can actually increment this total with each array entry added using the [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": id },
    {
       "$push": { "cbill_details": { "total-sell": 22, "price": 1512 } },
       "$inc": {
           "order-total-sell": 22
       }
    }
)
```

In that way, the total of all items in the array is already in the document, which is a property than can be directly queried and even indexed. So then just query directly:

```js
db.collecion.find({ "order-total-sell": { "$gt": 30 } })
```

That's going to be the most performant way to do this, so it's generally advised to keep the "totalled" properties within the document at all times, and maintain the total with each update applied.